# How to recursively return string value in C?

Tags: c, string, recursion, cs50

Trying to learn something here more than solve the specific problem. Please help me towards some best practices to apply in this situation, and if possible some clarification of why. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Basically I'm brute-force breaking a very simple hash algorithm, within known limits. Function tests possibilities of a string (within a length limit) against the hash, until it matches the hash passed. Then recursion should stop all iterations and return the string that matched. The iteration works, but when the answer is found, it seems that *each run of the function doesn't get the value returned by its call of the same function*.

Here's the code of the function, with extra comments for clarity:

```
//'hash' is the hash to be replicated
//'leading' is for recursive iteration (1st call should have leading=="")
//'limit' is the maximum string length to be tested

string crack(string hash, string leading, int limit)
{
    string cracked=NULL, force=NULL, test=NULL;

    //as per definition of C's crypt function - validated
    char salt[3] = {hash[0], hash[1], '\0'};

    // iterate letters of the alphabet - validated
    for(char c='A'; c<='z'; c++)
    {
        // append c at the end of string 'leading' - validated
        test = append(leading,c);

        // apply hash function to tested string - validated
        force = crypt(test,salt);

        // if hash replicated, store answer in 'cracked' - validated
        if(strcmp(hash,force)==0)
        {
            cracked = test;
        }
        else
        {
            // if within length limit, iterate next character - validated
            if(strlen(test)<=limit+1)
            {
                // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS
                // value received when solution found
                // is always empty string ("", not NULL)
                // tried replacing this with strcpy, same result
                cracked = crack_des(hash,test,limit);
            }
        }

        // if answer found, break out of loop - validated
        if(cracked){break;}

        // test only alphabetic characters - validated
        if(c=='Z'){c='a' - 1;}
    }

    free(test);

    // return NULL if not cracked to continue iteration on level below
    // this has something to do with the problem
    return cracked;
} // end of function
```

From the little bit I recall of pointers, I'd guess it is something with passing references instead of values, but I don't have enough knowledge to solve it. I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371761/recursion-in-c-not-returning-string-value), but this suggestion doesn't seem to solve the issue - I tried using strcpy and got the same results.

Disclaimer: this is an exercise in 2018's CS50 by Harvard at EDX. It won't affect my grading (have already submitted two perfect exercises for the week, which is what is required) but as stated above I'm looking to learn.

*Edit*: edited the tag back to C (as clarified in comments, string is from string.h, and append was coded by me and validated several times over - I'll get to TDD in a while). Thanks all for your comments; problem solved and lessons learned!

Comment: Did someone add a string type to C when I wasn't looking? Or is that a typedef for char*?

Comment: You mean C++? There is no `string` in C.

Comment: ...and so far as I know, there's no operator for conversion in a `bool` context for the one in C++, so `if(cracked){break;}` is suspect if the intent was C++.  Everything in the code seems consistent with it being a typdef.

Comment: Changed the `c` tag to `c++`.  The `append()` method is not a **C** method.  It is a **C++** method.

Comment: I'd put a print statement next to `cracked = test;` just to make sure you enter that case like you think you do.

Comment: Fix the submission so that there is a recursive function in it. It would also help to know how `string` and `append` are defined.

Comment: Is there are reason you are using recursion, and not a simple loop? If not, use a loop, because C++ does not promise tail call optimization -> at best inefficient code with extra function call overhead, at worst stack overflow. Use recursion only when you know it is actually useful or needed, and recursion depth is limited (usually *log(n)* of balanced tree traversals, partitioning sort algorithms, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, all! For those that questioned the string type, it exists in C with header string.h. Sorry for not clarifying that (I guess I could have used char* all the same, but then besides coding append I would have to code strlen and strcpy).

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b I did work with print statements all over - everything I noted down as `validated` has been validated that way, old school. I just removed them here for code clarity.

Comment: @hyde, as mentioned above, this is is C, not C++. But indeed, recursion was just a personal choice. That is the solution I saw at first to make it possible to work with different limits on the string length. Afterwards I saw other options, but I kinda like recursion :-). Thanks for the best practice tip, very clear and helpful.

Comment: @VitorFalleiros Right. Well, I believe C does not guarantee taill call optimization any more than C++ does, so the point stands. And yeah, recursion can be cool, but to really use it instead of loops, you need [a different language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#By_language).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a bug in the code, but I am not sure whether it is the root cause of your problem.

When the code hit the line:

```
strcmp(hash,force)==0
```

then you will assign the string pointed by 'test' to 'cracked':

```
cracked = test;
```

then this line is hit:

```
if(cracked){break;}
```

then the loop is breaked, and the next line:

```
free(test);
```

this line will free the string pointed by test, and remember that it is the same string pointed by 'cracked', thus you **returned a string which is already freed**.

What will happened to the string is dependent on your compiler and libc. You can try to fix this problem by allocating memory for 'cracked':

```
cracked = strdup(test);
```

Also, there are memory leaks caused by the 'test' and 'force' string, but they should be irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Did you assume string is std::string here? . If then `cracked = test;` does a copy, not keeping pointer. But I don't understand why `free(test)` is there for strings.

Comment: @PraAnj He is operating the strings with strcmp(), free the string by free(), and the tag is "C" instead of "C++", so I regard string as an typedef of char *

Comment: @PraAnj When I was answering the question, the tag is still "C", now it is edited by other people. I think it is quite obvious that in the question, the author is using strcmp/strlen/free to operate the "string" type. typedef char * is the only reasonable guess. And editing the tag to C++ without further confirm with the author is not responsible.

Comment: @YiZhenfei the OP has made no attempt to deny nor confirm whether their source code was **C**.  Given the information that we have, it's safe to assume that this is a **C++** post.  I agree with your statement; the tags will be edited again, if need be, when the OP states more information.

Comment: Thanks @YiZhenfei, indeed the freeing of `test` was the issue. I had had a full execution fail before and imagined it might be due to the memory leak caused by `test` and `force`, as you mentioned.

Comment: As for not confirming the tag, apologies - I needed a few hours of sleep. It is indeed C, not C++. The string type is from string.h and the append function I coded myself easily enough.

Comment: Great catch @YiZhenfei.